# Data evaluation from text file

Tags: java, arrays, file, sorting, text

I need some help. I dont know how to solve my problem. 
I have text file in this format:

```
personx 25
personz 2  
persony 5  
persony 7  
personi 55  
personx 25
```

I need to count the numbers for every person. The output should be "personx = 50" etc.
I can not use my old system where I knew there is 10 people. So I had 10 variables and I just went through the file with scanner and checked if line starts with "personx" then count the number to variable `personx` etc. I dont want to use these variables now. I dont want to change code after every new person.
How to solve this? I want to have this output sorted from highest to lowest:

```
personi = 55
personx = 50
persony = 12
personz = 2
```

Is that possible without using variables

```
personi, personx, persony, personz ?
```

My idea was to go through the file and scan the names. Save the name into an array and add another name into an array if that name is not in the array yet. So I will have the names.
Next I will scan the file again and check for the name and number. Check name + number and then save the number into another array on the same possition as the name in the first array. So I will have

```
Names[0] = "personi";
Count[0] = 55;
Names[1] = "personx";
Count[1] = 50;
```

And then I will just print these two arrays with for cycle.

I dont think that it is the best solution. How would you do it? Is there something better/faster/easier ? And how to solve that Sorting?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use a `Map<String, Integer>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can us `Map<String,Integer>`

In this case i used `TreeMap` which will sort everything for you. If you dont need sorting then just use `HashMap` instead of `TreeMap`.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap();
  try {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/iPhone/persons.txt")));
      String line = "";
      String [] person = new String[2];
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          person = line.split(" ");
          String name = person[0];
          int number = Integer.parseInt(person[1]);
          map.put(name,map.getOrDefault(name,0)+number);
      }
      reader.close();
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
  map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k + " = " + v));

}
```

persons.txt:

```
personx 25
personz 2  
persony 5  
persony 7  
personi 55  
personx 25
```

Output:

```
personi = 55
personx = 50
persony = 12
personz = 2
```

1) Can I use this on file where line is not in my format but it has for example.. this format ? "personx bla bla 25" ? Is it possible to convert it too? how?

Yes you can create method which will do it for you. You can use either string splits or some regex.

2) Why is there String [] person = new String[2]; ?

Mistake, it should be `String[1]`. Corrected now

3) what is String line = ""; ?

It is just new `String` where i'm storing every line that i read from file. As you can see, im assigning `reder.readLine()` in while loop. After that im just splitting it.

EDIT:
Changed code so person can have multiple params but will take only first as name and last as number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap();
          try {
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/iPhone/persons.txt")));
              String line = "";
              String [] person;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  person = line.split(" ");
                  String name = person[0];
                  int number = Integer.parseInt(person[person.length-1]);
                  map.put(name,map.getOrDefault(name,0)+number);
              }
              reader.close();
          } catch (IOException ioe) {
              ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
          map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k + " = " + v));
        }
```

persons.txt:

```
personx  asdasdas dasd asd a 25
personz 2  
persony asd asd asd a 5  
persony 7  
personi 55  
personx 25
```

output:

```
personi = 55
personx = 50
persony = 12
personz = 2
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply! Thats helped a lot! :)
I have few qeustions..
1) Can I use this on file where line is not in my format but it has for example.. this format ? "personx bla bla 25" ? Is it possible to convert it too? how?
2) Why is there String [] person = new String[2]; ? Why not String [] person = new String[1]; ?
3) what is String line = ""; ? :)

Comment: @Kym Answer edited, please take a look now. And let me know for example if input is "personx bla bla bla 25" what should be output? "personx 25" or "personx bla bla bla 25" ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) The output should be "personx 25"

Comment: And to make my question more specific.. - How to achieve the same output with the text input "personx bla bla 25" ?

Comment: Edited. you can try now :)

Comment: Just add try/catch in while loop, because you will get exception if you have string with only 1 param (for example you have line with "personx" only) @Kym

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working. But it does not sort them by numbers. It sort them by name. If there is personx = 125 it is still on the second line.

Comment: http://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/how-to-sort-a-treemap-by-value-in-java/

Comment: Nice. Thank you once again.